# TFS 2017 - Add default filter in Feature board

Tags: tfs

We are looking for a way to add a custom field as filter option in the Feature board.
Currently the Feature board shows Assigned To, Iteration, Work Item Type, Tags and Parent Work Item as filter options.
We would like to be able to filter on our release field.

I am not able to find a way to achieve this, can you confirm if this is indeed locked down ? or is there a way we can edit these fields to filter on ?

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to customize the `Filter cards`. I have submitted a User Voice at website below, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33501470-customize-the-filter-cards-on-tfs-kanban-board

Comment: Thanks for confirming and creating the user voice !